# Using jQuery to read a JSON file errors in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome

I have a JSON file here:

http://dalexl.webs.com/products.json

I'm trying to read it on my site with Javascript/jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("http://dalexl.webs.com/products.json")
```

*(Yes, I know that it isn't complete, I'm currently just trying to get it to load, I haven't worked on reading it yet)*

I tried having in my own sites directory (I'm using Dreamweaver locally on my HD).

```
$.getJSON("json/products.json")
```

---

The problem is, in Chrome (I'm not sure about other browsers), the console gives me this error:

*`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dalexl.webs.com/products.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`*

**or:**

*`XMLHttpRequest cannot load json/products.json. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`*

---

At first, reading about the problem online suggested that it was Chrome thinking that a website was trying to read files on my computer.  After moving the file online, however, the problem continues.

Does anybody have a solution to this?  If it isn't supposed to be supported, why does jQuery have a native method of doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the page on which the script executing the line

```
$.getJSON("http://dalexl.webs.com/products.json")
```

is also on `http://dalex1.webs.com`, you're running afoul of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), a restriction on what resources you can load via `XMLHttpRequest` (e.g., "ajax"). See the link for details.

Your options for getting around the SOP are:

- [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), which requires modifying the data you're returning, but in a trivial way.
- [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), a relatively recent standard which the server and browser would both need to support. (Recent versions of Firefox, Opera, and Chrome all support it with `XMLHttpRequest`; IE8 and above support it, but only via `XDomainRequest` object rather than the standard `XMLHttpRequest`. [Details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc709423.aspx#xdomainsec_secconcernswebapiwg).)
- In really tricky situations, you might look at using [YQL as a cross-domain proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax).

<s>Separately, note that the JSON you're returning is invalid (missing commas between properties), see [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) and others for validation tools.</s> It is now you've fixed it.

Comment: So, if I host the whole site on the webs account, it will work?  *-EDIT-* What if I hosted my own small little http server on my computer, would that work?

Comment: @DadeLamkins: As long as the requests are not crossing origins, yes, that will work. So if the page issuing the call is on `http://dalex1.webs.com` and the data being requested is also on `http://dalex1.webs.com`, that will work. If you run a local web server, and the page doing the request is on `http://localhost` and the data being requested is on `http://localhost`, that will work. It will not work for a page on `http://localhost` to request the data from `http://dalex1.webs.com` or vice-versa. Read the SOP link for details.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I've decided to run a local server so I don't have to re-upload every 2 seconds :)

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to open cross domain? See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: It didn't work when loading from my own filesystem either though.

Comment: @DadeLamkins: That's because the local filesystem is an origin (origin "null"). Some browsers allow origin null to retrieve anything from any origin, other browsers do not. Many don't allow the `file:///` protocol in ajax calls at all.

Answer (score 1):

http://dalexl.webs.com/products.json does not return valid json. I like using http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ for testing (when you press the "viewer" button you get an error).

You have three missing commas:

After: "url": "#1"

After: "url": "#2"

Before: "Cakes": {